# Calling method twice crashes application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, memory-management, graph

am writing an application that plots point on a graph and am using the below method to return an array of these points. I have two views, each displaying different graphs but both have this identical method. Whichever graph is used second causes the application to crash when it reaches the line "NSArray *reading ...". I can't figure out why but am guessing it may have something to do with memory management. Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this?

```
-(NSArray*)loadPoints{

    Vehicle *vehicle = [DataModel theDataModel].currentVehicle;

    NSArray *readings = [(NSArray*)vehicle.rVehicleMileage autorelease];

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dteDate" ascending:NO] autorelease];

    readings = [readings sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

    return readings;
}
```

Thanks,
  William

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *readings = [(NSArray*)vehicle.rVehicleMileage autorelease];
```

You should not call `-autorelease` on some object you don't own. Remove that `-autorelease` and it should run correctly.

Comment: Thanks KennyTM that worked perfectly, I was under the impression that anything that you returned from a method should be autoreleased, but I guess not

Comment: The array produced by `sortedArrayUsingDesriptors:` **is** autoreleased already.  If you wanted really wanted to, you could do `return [[readings retain] autorelease];`, but that isn't necessary.